# xpath getting the name in a certain pattern

Tags: xpath

I want to get a class name like the following:

```
class="hostHostGrid0_body"
```

The integer in between hostHostGrid and _body can change, but everything else I want it just like that in the order.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 you can use this:

```
//*[starts-with(@class,'hostHostGrid') and substring-after(@class,'_') = 'body']
```

to select *any* element containing *one* class. It will match tags in any context. It will match all three elements below:

```
<div class="hostHostGrid0_body">
    <span class="hostHostGrid123_body"/>
    <b class="hostHostGrid1_body">xxx</b>
</div>
```

Limitations: it doesn't restrict what is between them to a number. It can be anything, including spaces (ex: it will also match this: `class="hostHostGrid xyz abc_body"`)

This one allows for the class occurring among other classes:

```
//*[contains(substring-before(@class,'_body'),'hostHostGrid')]
```

It will match:

```
<div class="other-class hostHostGrid0_body">
    <span class="hostHostGrid123_body other-class"/>
    <b class="hostHostGrid1_body">xxx</b>
</div>
```

(it also has the same limitations - will match anything between 'hostHostGrid' and '_body')